# UObjectFinder versus UClassFinder; when is one better than the other?

Tags: unreal-4

I want to change the default pawn of my game and I decided to do it with c++.

I came up with this solution, which works fine:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FClassFinder<APawn> MyPawn(TEXT(" address..."));
        DefaultPawnClass=Pawn.Class;
```

However, I searched on the internet and found this approach used more often:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UClass> MyPawn(TEXT(" address..."));
        DefaultPawnClass=(UClass*)Pawn.Object;
```

What advantages does UObjectFinder have over UClassFinder?

Are there certain circumstances where one is preferable to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FObjectFinder` is used to find *any* `UObject`. `FClassFinder` is used to find any `UClass`. Note that a `UClass` itself is a `UObject`, so the object finder is the more general utility.

Since what you are ultimately trying to find here is a class, `FClassFinder` is the "better" option in the sense that it more clearly communicates your intent, and the result is itself already a `TSubclassOf<T>`.

Comment: But if object finder is more of a general utility thus when we  do pawn.object it must be returning a UObject right??

Comment: So we must downcast to come down the hierarchy ??

Comment: Correct. UObject is a base class of UClass.

Comment: Correct means that cast was necessary right?

Comment: The cast may not be necessary; if you look at the [documentation](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/ConstructorHelpers/FObjectFinder/index.html), the Object member is of type T*, so as long as you are supplying the exact type argument for T you want (UClass in this case), you don't need the cast.